# using numpy repeat simultaneously on arrays with distinct multiplicities but same dimension

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy, vectorization

I have two trival arrays of the same length, *tmp_reds* and *tmp_blues*:

```
npts = 4
tmp_reds = np.array(['red', 'red', 'red', 'red'])
tmp_blues = np.array(['blue', 'blue', 'blue', 'blue'])
```

I am using *np.repeat* to create multiplicity:

```
red_occupations = [1, 0, 1, 2]
blue_occupations = [0, 2, 0, 1]

x = np.repeat(tmp_reds, red_occupations)
y = np.repeat(tmp_blues, blue_occupations)

print(x)
['red' 'red' 'red' 'red']

print(y)
['blue' 'blue' 'blue']
```

What I want is the following composite of *x* and *y*:

```
desired_array = np.array(['red', 'blue', 'blue', 'red', 'red', 'red', 'blue'])
```

So, *desired_array* is defined in the following manner:

(1) Multiplicity from the first element of red_occupations is applied

(2) Multiplicity from the first element of blue_occupations is applied

(3) Multiplicity from the second element of red_occupations is applied

(4) Multiplicity from the second element of blue_occupations is applied

...

(2*npts-1) Multiplicity from the *npts* element of red_occupations is applied

(2*npts) Multiplicity from the *npts* element of blue_occupations is applied

So this seems like a straightforward generalization of the normal usage of np.repeat. Normally, np.repeat does exactly the above, but with a single array. Does anyone know some clever way to use multidimensional arrays that are then flattened, or some other similar trick, that can accomplish this with np.repeat?

I could always create *desired_array* without use of numpy, using a simple zipped for loop and successive list appends. However, the actual problem has npts ~ 1e7, and speed is critical.

Comment: All elements in `tmp_reds` are `red` and same for `tmp_blues` being always blue?

Comment: why not just create your desired array with slicing from the original ones?

Comment: Yes, Divikar, that's right

Comment: Not sure I follow Zachi, can you be a little more explicit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a generic case -

```
# Two 1D color arrays
tmp1 = np.array(['red', 'red', 'red', 'green'])
tmp2 = np.array(['white', 'black', 'blue', 'blue'])

# Multiplicity arrays
color1_occupations = [1, 0, 1, 2]
color2_occupations = [0, 2, 0, 1]

# Stack those two color arrays and two multiplicity arrays separately
tmp12 = np.column_stack((tmp1,tmp2))
color_occupations = np.column_stack((color1_occupations,color2_occupations))

# Use np.repeat to get stacked multiplicities for stacked color arrays
out = np.repeat(tmp12,color_occupations.ravel())
```

giving us -

```
In [180]: out
Out[180]: 
array(['red', 'black', 'black', 'red', 'green', 'green', 'blue'], 
      dtype='|S5')
```

Comment: Fantastic answer, @Divakar. This is exactly the numpy cleverness I was looking for.